# Excel If statement to sum if cell contains a certain string

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

I am trying to code an `IF` statement to sum based on certain criteria.

I have attached a screen shot for better understanding. Essentially what I want to achieve is this:

- In my screen shot Cell U4 is the sum of Cell R4:T4
- I want to incorporate a test so that if Cell O4 contains "yes" then sum and show the number
- But, if Cell O4 contains "No" then show me the text "fail"

Screen shot below, and as always thank you so much for any help you can give

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(O4="yes",SUM(R4:T4),"fail")`

this will yield `fail` for every value other than `"yes"`
if you want to check for any potential errors or blanks, use

`=IF(O4="yes",SUM(R4:T4),IF(O4="no","fail","ERROR"))`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the following formula:

`=IF(O4="yes",SUM(R4:T4),"fail")`

But that would mean that `fail` would return for all values that are not `yes`, not just `no`.

So alternatively, you could use this formula:

`=IF(O4="yes",SUM(R4:T4),IF(O4="no","fail","foo"))`

But you need to think about what happens if O4 is neither `yes` nor `no`.

HTH.

Comment: you're a minute too late, but identical answers heh

Comment: Haha but you edited to update for the Yes/No/Error thing ;-)

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed & Robin Mackenzie: The formula that actually worked for me is `=IF(O4="No","FAIL",SUM(R4:T4))`

Comment: @PhilipConnell - if you feel the answers from David and myself were useful, feel free to upvote. Your answer is the 'flip side of the coin' to our identical answers. Cheers, Robin

Answer (score 1):

Hi so I hope this helps someone as this site is amazing for helping Rookies like me out. I wanted a txt response to certain criteria and the formula that works in my example is `=IF(O4="No","FAIL",SUM(R4:T4))`

Comment: What your question asks for is something else, namely what we responded to you. Consider better wording, as what you seem to have wanted was "I want to incorporate a test so that if Cell O4 contains 'no' then show me the text 'fail', otherwise sum and show the number"

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed: I apologize for incorrect wording. I will be more vigilante with that in the future. Again thank you for taking the time to respond.